# Displaying Tables in Python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZURs.png)

Hello guys! I need a help with my homework as I need to print these nnumber as displayed on the picture. I believe you will help me, ty!

https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48890243266_579ef6e9dc_o.png

Comment: Please post code showing what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better for you to learn more about the base syntax of python

```py
print('a1\ta2\ta3')
for i in range(1, 5):
    print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(i,i**3,i**4))
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much! Really appreaciate it !

Comment: I also have a few otehr questions releated to it, coudl you help with those also? They are also kinda simple , but it is my first day with python :)